# Compare two large CSV files and making a third one from the difference

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a problem where I need to compare two large CSV Files (Approx 5 to 8 GB) and have to make a third CSV file from their difference.
Any suggestion pointer for supported libraries for the same or any reference to get started

e.g

```js
File 1.csv

+---+------+------+
|ID |value1|value2|
+---+------+------+
|  1|    a|   Ran1|
|  2|    b|   Ran2|
+---+-----+-------+

File 2.csv

+---+------+------+
|ID |value1|value2|
+---+------+------+
|  3|    c|   Ran3|
|  2|    b|   Ran2|
+---+-----+-------+

Schema of both file is same

Result - file 3.csv
File 2.csv

+---+------+------+
|ID |value1|value2|
+---+------+------+
|  2|    b|   Ran2|
+---+-----+-------+
```

Comment: For handling the CSV files you may take a look at [**cormorant**](https://christopherdavenport.github.io/cormorant/). Addiotionally, given there will be large files, I wouldn't use standar scala collections - but instead, some form of Streaming _(for example [**fs2**](http://fs2.io/))_. Now, I don't really understand what exactly you mean with _"difference"_.

Comment: For streaming large files, something like [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.18/stream/index.html) is pretty common.

Comment: By "difference", do you mean a textual difference, or content difference? "4.50" is textually different than "4.5", but is not different if the field is treated as a number.

Comment: If there is a difference, how do you resynchronize the two sources? Do you look for the next non-differing line, or do you have key fields, such as a timestamp, that guarantees ordered access?

Comment: @BobDalgleish - Schema of both csv is same, their is textual difference in both file

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez will checkout that.  added a example to show what i want to achieve

Comment: Guys, Is it possible to load data in NoSQL DB and do the comparison via No SQL. what you suggest?